# Homomorphism from C* into itself having ker = R>0

Tags: group-theory

So I feel like I must be missing an easy example here... I'm trying to find a homomorphism from the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ into itself such that its kernel is the positive reals.

Obvious near-misses are $\phi(z)=\phi(r\text{e}^{i\theta})=\theta$ (it's a homomorphism into the $\mathbb{R}$ under addition) and $\psi(z)=\psi(r\text{e}^{i\theta})=r$ (homomorphism into the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}$, and therefore into the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, but $\text{ker}\psi=\{0\} \ne \mathbb{R} \ge 0$). And I have written down about a dozen other types of function that I thought I would try (e.g. permutations of $\phi(z)=\phi(a+ib)=\text{sgn}(a)(+/*)b$ ...), but I can't seem to find a homomorphism such that $\varphi(z_{0})=\varphi(a+i0)=1$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint: if you can find a homomorphism $\psi$ such that $\psi(x) = x$ precisely when $x$ is a positive real number, then $\phi(x) = \psi(x)x^{-1}$ will do.

Comment: **Hint:** Normalize

Comment: Dear user, As an aside, the kernel of $\psi(z) = r$ is not $\{0\}$ (which doesn't even belong to $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$), but rather the unit circle. Regards,

Comment: P.S. Regarding your actual question, you are looking for a homomorphism which takes a positive real number to $1$.  So what will it do to $r e^{i\theta}$?

Comment: Yep, so I figured this out as soon as I woke up - probably proving that I needed sleep. Sometimes it's best to just put down the pencil and lay down. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $f: re^{i\theta} \rightarrow e^{i \theta}$ will do.